# How to update a behavior property from custom element

Tags: polymer

I am learning using [behaviors](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/behaviors), and stuck at a problem where updating a behavior property from a custom element is not reflecting in another custom element.
Ex: I have created a behavior.html, profile.html, toolbar.html. Profile and Toolbar are using behavior.html. So When user performs a specific action in profile.html, I am updating a property of the behavior.html. Bur toolbar.html is not displaying the updated value.

I will paste the sample snippets below, please let me know if you have any suggestions on where I am doing wrong.

behavior.html

```
<script>
window.MyBehaviors = window.MyBehaviors || {};
MyBehaviors.SheetsBehaviorImpl = {
        properties: {
            isActiveUser: {
                type: Boolean,
                value: false,
                notify: true
            }
    }
MyBehaviors.SheetsBehavior = [
    Polymer.AppNetworkStatusBehavior,
    MyBehaviors.SheetsBehaviorImpl
];
```

profile.html

```
    ..... 
isUserRegisted: function(changeRecord) {
      MyBehaviors.SheetsBehaviorImpl.properties.isActiveUser = this.userlist.approved;
      //Do some more checks and return a  boolean based on the checks
   }, .....
```

toolbar.html

```
<span>{{isActiveUser}}</span>
```

Toolbar is always showing me false, because thats what I initialized to. Toolbar also share another property "online" from AppNetworkStatusBehavior, and that property is reflecting fine always. ie., if I go offline it reflects offline and if come online then its showing me online. So I assuming the behaviors are working fine in toolbar, it seems only problem updating my own properties.

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to use `behavior` in wrong way cause it only share some code between components. So you can use another solution for it like data binding or firing some [custom event](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events) and set a property value inside another element

Comment: I see! Yeah my current implementation is data binding, and it is working fine. But when I came across this I felt its more easy when using multiple custom elements. Because AppNetworkStatusBehavior is what making a variable "online" available across all my elements, and If go Offline all my elements are responding. So I thought I can achieve something like that for some basic properties that share across different custom elements.

Comment: Yup, you can use global variable for this case